# How come my ElasticSearch ingest pipelines with multiple grok patterns are all failing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on getting the Tomcat logs of some applications correctly processed in ElasticSearch, but unfortunately my ingest pipelines with multiple grok processors aren't working and they all end up in the failed-index.

catalina.out

```
13-Feb-2018 16:04:48.446 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
```

catalina.log

```
13-Feb-2018 16:00:35.385 SEVERE [monkey.co.uk-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/webapps/email.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[monkey.co.uk].StandardContext[/email]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my ingest pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/tomcat_all

{  
   "description":"Pipeline tomcat_all",
   "on_failure":[  
      {  
         "set":{  
            "field":"_index",
            "value":"failed-{{ _index }}"
         }
      }
   ],
   "processors":[  
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:type_log}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}\\|-%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}in%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{MONTHDAY}[/-]%{MONTH}[/-]%{YEAR} %{TIME}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "grok":{  
            "field":"message",
            "patterns":[  
               "%{MONTHDAY}.%{MONTHNUM}.%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Grok patterns:

```
%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:type_log}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}\\|-%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}in%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{MONTHDAY}[/-]%{MONTH}[/-]%{YEAR} %{TIME}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
%{MONTHDAY}.%{MONTHNUM}.%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}
```

I have tried the grok patterns manually at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com and that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to list all patterns inside patterns [] separated with commas instead of having multiple groks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for contributing on StackOverflow. Pasting the code as text, as well as providing a few more details on why this will work and for example, why the OP's efforts didn't, would increase the answer's quality.